# I have an error when opening an old video game on Virtual Machine. Error says 'Unable to initialize display. Width: 800, Height: 600, Depth: 32'

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, display, gaming

I want to play an old game through virtual machine, but when I click 'open', it comes up with an error saying, **'Unable to initialize display. Width: 800, Height: 600, Depth: 32'**

I'm using Windows XP, and the game I set up is Playboy - The Mansion.

*Firstly*, I have tried changing the display setting on windows XP to 800 by 600 and 32, but it still doesn't work. I have also tried changing it to the highest setting, 1600 by 1200 and 32, but with no luck.

*Secondly*, I have tried adding Guest additions, because I read it could fix the problem, however the error persists.

*Thirdly*, I have gone to preferences in the Virtual Box Manager, and changed the display to be 1600 by 1200, However it still doesn't work.

I have looked countlessly online, but can't find a solution that fixes my problem, so any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

*I'm not very computer savvy, sorry.

Here's a pic of the error:

[image]

Comment: It probably can't work in a VM due to the virtualized hardware. It probably expects one known graphics card.

Comment: That seems to be the case - https://www.game-debate.com/games/index.php?g_id=2906&game=Playboy:%20The%20Mansion - , it needs an actual Nvidia or ATI

Comment: Oh, I see thank you